# Contour Error for tracking a continous trajectory

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, optimization, curves, control-theory

Consider the following linear discrete system

$$ \xi_{k+1} = A\xi_k + Bu_k$$

where $x_k \in  \mathbb{R} $ and $y_K \in \mathbb{R}$ denote the $x$- and $y$-axis displacements at time $k$, $\xi_k \in \mathbb{R^n}$ denotes the system states and $u_k \in \mathbb{R^{n_u}}$ is the input. The objective is to steer along a continuously differentiable and bounded 2-D geometric path $(x^d(\theta),(y^d(\theta))$. It is
assumed that the desired path $(x^d(\theta),(y^d(\theta))$ is parameterised by arc length, i.e. $ds/dθ = 1$, where $s$ denotes the distance travelled along the path.

The contouring error $\epsilon_k^c$ is defined as the normal deviation from the desired path and can be expressed as

$$ \epsilon_k^c = \sin\phi(\theta^r)(x_k - x^d(\theta^r)) - \cos\phi(\theta^r)(y_k - y^d(\theta^r)) $$
Model predictive contour controller is a type of MPD controller that follows a predfined path $X^{ref}$ and $Y^{ref}$.

$$\phi(\theta^r) = \arctan(\frac{\nabla y^d(\theta^r)}{\nabla x^d(\theta^r)}), \nabla f(\theta^r) = \frac{df(\theta)}{d\theta}\bigg|_{\theta=\theta^r}$$

where $\theta^r(x, y)$ is the value of the path parameter at which the distance between the point $(x^d(\theta),y^d(\theta))$ and $(x,y)$ is minimal as per [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxdnl.png).

How do I derive the equation of contouring error $\epsilon_k^c$?

Comment: Your post is not very clear. Some variables do not seem to have been properly defined; e.g. $\theta^s$. Please provide more details.

Comment: Added a comment on x^d(theta), y^d(theta)  and what it means.